# ¿Como pasar de spawn a spawnSync?

Tags: nodejs

Estoy haciendo una consola bash utilizando node.js. Tengo utilizar spawnSync en lugar de spawn. ¿Como hago para que cuando se produzca una salida estandar se emita un evento, lo capture y lo mande al cliente a traves de un socket?

El código con spawn sería algo así:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var shell = spawn('/bin/bash');

shell.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
   socket.emit('stdout', data);
});

socket.on('stdin', function(command) {
    shell.stdin.write(command+"\n") || socket.emit('disable');
});
```

Necesito saber como hacer algo equivalente con spawnSync. Si necesitais mas codigo o que aclare algo preguntad sin miedo.

Edit: por lo que ha explicado Gustavo no es viable hacerlo con spawnSync ¿Existe alguna manera de saber si un comando ha finalizado (correcta o incorrectamente)? El caso es que hay comandos como cd que no emiten salida y necesito un "algo" (sea un evento preferiblemente) que me indique que ha finalizado.

Answer (score 1):

La función[`child_process.spawnSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) es síncrona, como su nombre lo indica. Al igual que [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) por ejemplo, se bloqueará el EventLoop hasta que haya terminado su ejecución en el stack. En el caso de `spawnSync`, **el EventLoop se bloqueará hasta que el proceso haya sido cerrado**.

El modo de uso es simple:

```
const command = spawnSync('ifconfig', ['eth0']);
// el resto de código se ejecutará cuando se termine el proceso
const outtext = command.output[1];
console.log(outtext); // imprime información de la interface de red
socket.broadcast(outtext);
```

Comment: Gracias, por lo que explicas spawnSync no sirve para hacer una consola bash. ¿Sabes de alguna forma de averiguar cuando un comando sin salida por pantalla como cd ha finalizado?